# How to send click events to Google Analytics via Selenium?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, google-analytics

I am testing website Google Analytics event capture via Selenium Java based test automation application. The test website is fully integrated and setup with GA. When I click on links manually in the browser, I can see the events getting recorded in GA.

In the test Automation script, all the page load events are recorded in GA. However, when I a click the events in code, the corresponding event does not appear in GA. Please note, if I click the same element in the browser manually, the event does get recorded.

I have debugged my code, and the element is indeed getting clicked in Selenium.

I am using latest Chrome Driver browser for test automation.

The element in question has all the Google Analytics event defined in the following tag format:

```
   <li action='Button Click' href='/' label='Home'>
     <div>
       <span>
          <a>Home</a>
       </span>
    </div>
   </li>
```

In Selenium, I am extracting **`<li>`** the element using XPath and clicking it. I've also tried extracting **`<a>`** and clicking but I still don't see recorded events in Google Analytics Dashboard

Comment: Where is your code that you are using to click?